# how to solve heroku/grails memory issue?

Tags: grails, heroku

I'm having trouble when I want to deploy my grails backend to heroku. I'm getting memory issues, where I didn't get hose in the past...

What could be the reason for this?
In the image iI added, you can see an example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [Burt's blog](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1964) where he mentioned about his new plugins mainly meant for Heroku. May be this can add more light to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I went form heroku to appfog now, because I get some more resources there.
But if anyone knows if there's anothere reason for this huge memory usage, let me know.

Thanks